# Unable to pause activity?

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

I'm new to Android development. I wrote this code and I just can't figure out what's causing my app to crash. It's telling me that the activity wasn't able to be paused. I'm sure it's something I'm leaving out. I wrote very similar code that has worked in the past, so I'm just not sure where to start.

**SplashActivity.java**

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
        Animation twistIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.twist_in);
        logo.startAnimation(twistIn);
        twistIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
        {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
            {
                return; // do nothing
            }
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
            {
                return; // do nothing
            }
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        TextView logo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
        logo.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

And here's LogCat complaining:

```
04-04 02:09:10.460: W/dalvikvm(12531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.swapwords/com.swapwords.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at com.swapwords.SplashActivity.onPause(SplashActivity.java:57)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3893)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1194)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
04-04 02:09:10.480: E/AndroidRuntime(12531):    ... 12 more
04-04 02:09:12.452: I/dalvikvm(12531): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
04-04 02:09:12.452: I/dalvikvm(12531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-04 02:09:18.878: I/dalvikvm(12531): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
04-04 02:09:18.878: I/dalvikvm(12531): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I'm just lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
```

instead of

```
TextView logo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
```

in `onPause()` method because currently you are trying to cast `ImageView`(which you have added in xml layout) to `TextView`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to refer ImageView with Textview
so it throws `ClassCastException`

Change this

```
 TextView logo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
```

to this

```
 ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
```

Answer (score 1):

See this line in Oncreate() method

```
 ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
```

And **onPause() method** use have written **TextView instead of ImageView** like above

```
    TextView logo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewLogo);
```

So this is giving you classcast exception.. Change **TextView to ImageView**